# Does the VCC Output pin always give out a consistent 5V Voltage supply? What is the current output?

Tags: power, atmega328

Does the VCC Output pin always give out a consistent 5V Voltage supply? What is the current output?

This is the Chip I have. On the chip it says ProMini R160JAC6v. and When i program it. It programs under 5V 16MHz with ATmega 328

[image: 5V 16MHz with ATmega 328. If I want to power a 3.3V bluetooth chip can I do it with my board?]

Here is the bluetooth chip I am powering:

[image: Back Side]

Comment: VCC is likely an input.  What is on the other end of the yellow wire that goes off the pic?

Answer (score 1):

If you power from USB the vcc pin gives you the voltage that USB is providing. Somewhere between 4.75 and 5.25v.

If you use external power it provides 5v since that is what the regulator provides.

The current limit is either the limit of the usb port or the limit of the regulator on your board. Check the datasheet for that regulator (hint: read the schematic to find the model of the regulator).

Comment: Where can I find the USB 5v pon? I've been having a hard time finding the data sheet for that particular board. Maybe I'm looking in the wrong places? I've just tried typing in the specs of the board in google but havn't gotten the specs for that board.

Comment: If it is a genuine arduino the schematic will be on the arduino website. If it is a cheap chinese copy, you are on your own. It looks like an LM1117-5, and as such will most likely be 800mA. Pon = pin translated through my tablet's onscreen keyboard. Edited it.

Comment: And then there are these concerns:  https://provideyourown.com/2012/secret-arduino-voltmeter-measure-battery-voltage/